# Почему не подгружается google maps при перемещении мышью?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Подключен вывод *google maps*, карта отображается, но при перемещении мышкой в стороны, продолжение карты не подгружается. Так же иконки увелечения и уменьшения как бы размазаны. Кто сталкивался, подскажите куда копать. Вот сайт http://goo.gl/vz2ED8 нужно нажать на поиск, выбрать товар и уже в полном описании товара есть таб location. Пишу с мобильного, поэтому не могу выложить код

Comment: windows 10 Google Chrome все хорошо, в каком браузере и на каком девайсе не работает?

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, уже сделал просто. Проблема была в некорректном стиле.